# Generate a Google Sitemap from Text file

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have a text file that contains a bunch of URL's that need to be generated to a Google sitemap. I came across this blog post that sort of helped me: http://www.isurinder.com/blog/post/2012/07/31/Generate-Google-Sitemap-From-A-List-of-Urls-In-A-Text-File.aspx

How can I modify the code to change sitemap info such as date and priority?

Comment: But in the post have in the line 44 about priority... you can to put a new line with the date... but is cool if you get the date of your page get in a database...